# How to use Modal Window in Asp.net which can work like dialog in desktop apps?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, modal-dialog

I have used many *jquery* modals for work in *php*, but nothing works like desktop application separate panel. I mean, whenever we work in it, many complications of *css* and *javascript* come.

Is there any simple modal in which i can pass an *asp* page, so it will open like a dialog, which must be not like *jquery* modals which get disturb with simple things like a *javascripts*, *css* etc. Does *.net* have some better solution for this?

Regards
Atif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *AjaxToolKit* [ModalPopup](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx) control.

Answer (score 1):

[Jquery model dialog](http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-use-jquery-dialog-in-aspnet.html) is a good choice.You can easily integrate this with asp.net.

you may use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) Dialog Or [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) and other available Plugins.

You Can Execute every javascript/jQuery Code Serverside through using the [RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx)

```
 public void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string script = "$('#specificid').dialog('open');";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "popup", script, true);
 }
```